# SQL Server Server Properties

Tags: sql-server

I want to change the following server properties and settings in the SQL Server 2012. I just want to change the language from English(United States) to English(United Kingdom). Please suggests me the possible ways in order to get through.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language setting of the server doesn't matter, that's just a default setting for new added user, where you haven't define a language setting.

You have to change the language for your used account in SQL Server. In SSMS goto "Security" => "Logins" and open the properties of your account, at the bottom of the dialog you will find "Default language", I guess it's now "English", change it to "British English".

Or us a T-SQL Command:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [YourAccountName] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[British]
GO
```

Source : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/917d9534-ca26-4321-ab5a-1bf084cc7ee3/how-can-i-change-language-from-us-english-to-uk-english?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: Thanks for reply, what if there are hundreds of users logins, do I've to manually change each Default Language? Or is there any better way?

Comment: You can execute the above script on different user logins to set the prefered language. Use the EXECUTE AS command.

Comment: Actually I want to change only the default date format of SQL Server from US to British, for this reason I'm using this approach. Is there any way to get the default British date format permanently other than this approach?

Comment: @JanshairKhan , No. The default language for the Instance cannot be changed without Deinstalling and Reinstalling SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52402/how-to-change-default-language-of-sql-server-management-studio-2008r2

But, see that this is for SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."